# Convert JSON with different types of objects (strings, array) to Map

Tags: arrays, json, hive, brickhouse

I am trying to convert a JSON object to a map object in Hive using the brickhouse lib `brickhouse.udf.json.FromJsonUDF``.

The problem is, that my json object contains different types of values: string and one array of another arrays.

My json looks like this:

```
'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":[["0","1","nnn"],["1","3","mmm"],["1","3","ggg"],["1","5","kkk"],["4","5","ppp"]]}'
```

I can either read correctly the array of arrays element (`key4`) using the following:

```
select from_json('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":[["0","1","nnn"],["1","3","mmm"],["1","3","ggg"],["1","5","kkk"],["4","5","ppp"]]}', 'map<string,array<array<string>>>') from my_table limit 1;

Which gives me:

{"key1":[],"key3":[],"key2":[],"key4":[["0","1","nnn"],["1","3","mmm"],["1","3","ggg"],["1","5","kkk"],["4","5","ppp"]]}
```

As you can see all the elements but `key4` are empty.

Or I am able to read other elements but `key4` using:

```
select from_json('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":[["0","1","nnn"],["1","3","mmm"],["1","3","ggg"],["1","5","kkk"],["4","5","ppp"]]}', 'map<string,string>') from my_table limit 1;

Which gives me:

{"key1":"value1","key3":"value3","key2":"value2","key4":null}
```

But how can I convert all the elements correctly to key-value pairs on the resulting map object?

**EDITED**:

My actual data is an array of two components which are json objects:

```
[{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}{"key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5","key6":[["0","1","nnn"],["1","3","mmm"],["1","3","ggg"],["1","5","kkk"],["4","5","ppp"]]}]
```

Is it possible to create a `struct` object which contains the two json objects as two map objects so that I can access the first or second struct element and then select the value of the correspnding map object using a key?

For example: assuming my desired endresult is called `struct_result` I would access `value1` from the first component like:

```
struct_result.t1["key1"]
```

which would give me "value1".

Is it possible to achieve this with this lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using named_structs. You need to create a named_struct, and specify the types for each of the keys independently.

For example

```
select_from_json('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":[["0","1","nnn"],["1","3","mmm"],["1","3","ggg"],["1","5","kkk"],["4","5","ppp"]]}',
    named_struct("key1","", "key2", "", "key3", ""
        "key4", array(array("")))
from my_table;
```

This creates a template object using the 'named_struct' UDF, or you can use the equivalent string type definition.